# R grid and gridExtra: tableGrob doesn't respect width and height in viewport

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

I want to place several tables on a `ggplot2` figure, at different locations, in different sizes, and in a way that they're dynamically resized. I welcome any better solution, but my idea was to use viewports to achieve all these aims (`grid.table` does have a `vp` argument).

However, it seems that `tableGrob` simply disregards the `width` and `height` settings of the `vp`! (Interestingly, it does understand `x` and `y`.) Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library( grid )
library( gridExtra )
data( iris )

grid.newpage()
grid.rect( vp = viewport( x = 0.4, y = 0.4, width = 0.3, height = 0.3 ) )
grid.table( iris[ 1:3, 1:2 ], vp = viewport( x = 0.4, y = 0.4, width = 0.3, height = 0.3 ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

`tableGrob` by default extends to fit the text at a given font size; if you want it to stretch to the viewport you have to manually assign custom widths/heights, at the risk of having content overflow.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
data(iris)

grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(x = 0.4, y = 0.4, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) 
grid.rect(vp = vp)
tg <- tableGrob(iris[1:3, 1:2], vp = vp)
tg$widths[-1] <- rep(unit(1/2,"null"), 2)
tg$heights <- rep(unit(1/nrow(tg), "null"), nrow(tg))
grid.draw(tg)
```

[image: tableGrob image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to me that your solution works perfectly if I enlarge the figure, but if I shrunk it, it'll - instead of resizing the content - simply clip it. (As you already predicted in your description.) Is it possible to solve this one, i.e. to dynamically resize the content? Just as a usual viewport behaves.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to me that your solution works perfectly if I enlarge the figure, but if I shrunk it, it'll - instead of resizing the content - simply clip it. (As you already predicted in your description.) Is it possible to solve this one, i.e. to dynamically resize the content? Just as a usual viewport behaves.